# Find equilibrium points of the system

Tags: dynamical-systems, stability-in-odes

> Find equilibrium points of the system
>
> $x_{n+1}=\frac{\alpha x_n}{1+\beta x_n}$ where $\alpha>1,\beta >0$.
>
> Are they stable?

Can someone kindly say what is meant by finding equilibrium points of the system?

I don't understand the question. I got this question in a competitive exam I sat today.

Comment: This is a projective transformation.

Comment: Have you looked at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equilibrium_point)? Please also give more context about the competition (what level is it? what topics does it cover?) so that we can better help.

Comment: MMA gives this here $$\left\{\left\{y(n)\to \frac{\alpha -1}{\beta +c_1
   \left(\frac{1}{\alpha }\right)^{n-2}-c_1
   \left(\frac{1}{\alpha }\right)^{n-1}-\beta 
   \left(\frac{1}{\alpha }\right)^n}\right\}\right\}$$

Answer (score 0):

If there are any equilibrium points, they are solutions of the fixed-point equation
$$
x=\frac{αx}{1+βx}
$$
which can be transformed into a quadratic equation and solved as such.

---

One can get an explicit solution of the iteration by setting $x_n=\frac{p_n}{q_n}$ and identifying the denominators with denominators etc. to get
\begin{align}
p_{n+1}&=αp_n&&\implies& p_n&=α^np_0\\
q_{n+1}&=q_n+βp_n&&\implies& q_n&=q_0+β\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}α^kp_0=q_0+β\frac{α^n-1}{α-1}p_0
\end{align}

Comment: i am getting $x=0,x=\frac{\alpha-1}{\beta}>0$

Comment: so only one equilibrium point exists & it is unstable?

Comment: No, the explicit solution looks rather stable, after canceling out $α^n$ to get $$x_n=\frac{p_n}{q_n}=\frac{x_0}{α^{-n}+β\frac{1-α^{-n}}{α-1}x_0}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Your equation can be written as
$$-{\frac {x \left( -\beta\,x+\alpha-1 \right) }{\beta\,x+1}}=0$$